# how to find the second largest value in the tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am not getting the logic of how to find the second largest element in a tree.

```
public static int largestR(TreeNode<Integer> root){
    if(root==null){
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    int max=root.data;
    for(int i=0;i<root.children.size();i++){

        int n=largestR(root.children.get(i));
        if(max<n){
            max=n;
        }
    }   
    return max;
}
```

The tree is not binary a node can have any number of children .

It would be great if you can give me algorithm of code for its solution

Thanks.

Comment: Well, do you know how to get the largest value in the tree? It's pretty much the same as that, except you keep track of the 2 largest values, not just 1.

Comment: i know how to get largest value .

Comment: If you share your code showing how you've done it for the largest, we can suggest how to change that for 2nd largest.

Comment: but it would be great if you can provide me algorithm to find the second largest element

Comment: Copy tree. Find largest of copied tree. Remove it from copied tree and find again largest :)

Comment: @nishant [edit] your question and add the code there. It is impossible to read in comments.

Comment: @AndyTurner i have put my code . please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meed store 2 numbers instead of 1.

Here my implementation (not sure that syntax is correct):

```
public static void PushAnswer(int[] m, int value)
{
    if (m[1] >= value) return;
    if (m[0] >= value)
    {
        m[1] = value;
        return;
    }

    m[1] = m[0];
    m[0] = value;
}

public static void largestR(TreeNode<Integer> root, int[] answer)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    PushAnswer(answer, root.data);
    for (int i = 0; i < root.children.size(); i++)
    {
        largestR(root.children.get(i));
    }
}

public static int[] getLargestR(TreeNode<Integer> root)
{
    int[] answer = new int[2];
    answer[0] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    answer[1] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    largestR(root, answer);

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: This is basically correct. Well done, although I personally wouldn't use an array but just pass 2 variables as it's better for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (not very efficient, but working) algorithm. You've stated you know how to find the highest element in a list. Good. Remove that element. Find the highest element again!

Alternatively: Sort the tree by using some sorting algorithm and take the second element.

Still inefficient though. Best is to write your own method which keeps track of the two largest elements at all times.

Comment: Thanks . but can you please tell me how ?

Comment: Your edited code in the question is wrong, it will only look at the top level of the tree, you need to use recursion to find all children. But in the current state of the code, you would add an addition variable: `max2` of which the logic you can figure out for yourself ;) Basically whenever a child is greater than current max: max that the new max and set the old max equal to `max2`.

Comment: my code won't work for finding largest element?

Comment: Sorry I see it now, Disregard my previous comment =)

Comment: ok but can you tell me how to use max2 variable :D

Comment: I believe Толя already showed it more or less in his answer ;) I personally wouldn't use an array, but the idea is correct